# Defer in jQuery cdn and conflict with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, pagespeed

I use defer in the links to the cdn jQuery libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" defer>
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" defer></script>
```

It seemed a good solution to the Google Page Speed requirements. If I do not use defer Google Page Speed says: Remove Render-Blocking Javascript

```
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
```

But, as soon as I use defer, jQuery ui does not work. For instance, this piece of code needs ui. When I add defer, the animate does not happen.
jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color:'blue' },1000);
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="button">SOMETHING</div>
```

Why defer cause problems with jQuery UI and how to solve that?

Comment: Do you get some kind of console error? If so that would be helpful

Comment: Since you did not include a full example, it's hard to know how you are executing the code. Please wrap your code in `$(function(){ //your code });` to ensure that the jQuery is not running until the DOM and all Elements are loaded, such as the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on deferred scripts in your inline javascript code. You have to wait for the event **DOMContentLoaded**, which is fired after all deferred scripts are loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // now deferred scripts are loaded.
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({ color:'blue' },1000);
    });
});
```